# IOS8 widget todays extension issue

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, today-extension

I am newbie in storyboards and auto layouts/constraints. I have to show one of three different views and some times full three views in widget todays extension iOS8 at specific time and I am using IBOutlets and storyboard with auto layout and constraints because it is universal build. Once I hide the specific view it will leave empty space in others views as I came to know that constraints are still there so it is.... but I have tried to remove the view from superview and set

```
self.exampleView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
```

but all in vain

[image: full view : scenario :1]

next scenario:

[image]

I hope i get out of this !

Comment: set your `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO`. Do you call `[view setNeedsLayout]`?

Comment: I have  view1 , view2 , view3 and doing like this // 
    _view2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    _view2.hidden = YES;
    [_view2 setNeedsLayout];   like this you mean ?   @Crazyrems

Comment: The `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` may be what you want, but it creates supplementary constraints at runtime _(which may be undesirable)_. `setNeedsLayout` forces to layout before the next draw operation. So, yes it's probably what you must do. If you don't see any changes, try to create more/different/change your constraint priorities to the needs of your layout. I'm looking for a way to do what you want.